# CAS AD LDAP 32 error

Tags: active-directory, ldap, cas

I am seeing this when I try to login with CAS which is authenticating against AD over LDAP.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet cas threw exception
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001E5, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    ''
]; remaining name '/'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3092)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3013)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2820)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1829)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1752)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:368)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:338)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:257)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$3.executeSearch(LdapTemplate.java:231)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:293)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:237)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:588)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:546)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:421)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:441)
```

Up to that point I was authenticated by the BindLdapAuthenticationHandler, resolved, it generated a query builder and then threw this.

I think it is failing when it is trying to get attributes back. Why is the `remaining name '/'`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remaining name is a part of a DN that wasn't actually found at a certain level of a DIT. For example when you search `cn=johns,ou=marketing,dc=example,dc=com` and `ou=marketing,dc=example,dc=com` exists but `cn=johns` does not exists inside of `ou=marketing` then the remaning name would be `cn=johns`.

'/' does not look like a valid RDN. I would recommend to verify what you pass as a search base. Most likely it's an invalid DN string.

Comment: I instead got an empty remaining name, that is, "", which looks even stranger, issue is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39372374/5606016) (and it actually has an open bounty)

Answer (score 3):

LDAP error code 32 means "no such object", in this case, perhaps the base object of the search did not exist.

Comment: I can confirm that this was the cause of the problem, an empty base object.