# Java Spring LDAP Auth: always failed but works fine for testing similar configurations in Nodejs

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I am pretty new for Java/Spring. If need more information, please don't hesitate to point out.

First, I tested below codes **in Javascript(nodejs) which worked fine**.

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: 'ldap://xx.xx.xx.xx:389'
});

client.bind('domain\\user1', 'user1_password', function (err) {

  if (err) {
    throw err;
    return
  }
  var opts = {
    filter: '(sAMAccountName=user2)',
    scope: 'sub',
    attributes: ['l', 'sn', 'cn', 'mail', 'displayName', 'postalCode', 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName', 'telephoneNumber' ]
  };
  client.search('dc=aaa,dc=bbb,dc=ccc', opts, function(err, res) {
    res.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {
      Object.entries(entry.object).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        console.log('Found Attribute: ', key, '; value:', value)
      })
    });
  });
```

Then follow this guide:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/110491-how-to-modify-authority-after-loading-it-from-ldap

I applied the configurations **which are same as above** into spring/security.xml, like:

```
<bean id="customUserContextMapper" class="com.my.own.util.CustomUserDetailsMapper"/>
<sec:authentication-manager>
  <sec:ldap-authentication-provider
    user-search-base="dc=aaa,dc=bbb,dc=ccc"
    user-search-filter="(sAMAccountName={0})"
    user-context-mapper-ref="customUserContextMapper" 
  />
</sec:authentication-manager>
<sec:ldap-server url="ldap://xx.xx.xx.xx:389/"
     manager-dn="domain\user1" 
     manager-password="user1_password" 
/>
```

But **it failed**.

1. If submitted (http-post) one form (*username uses domain\username*) like `username=domain%5Cuser1&password=user1_password&submit=Login`, it returned **Reason: Bad credentials**
2. If submitted (http-post) one form (*username doesn't enclose domain*) like `username=user1&password=user1_password&submit=Login`, it returned **500 error**:

   org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001E5, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
       ''
   ]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001E5, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
       ''
   ]; remaining name ''

For **the first case**, it seems the entry exists but failed to validate the password. so return **bad credentials**.

For **the second case**, the error seems to say *search filter is wrong* ( as [CAS AD LDAP 32 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172667/cas-ad-ldap-32-error) pointed out)

But I am sure I typed in correct username and password, and the search-filter is same as which already been tested in nodejs.

Already stuggled with this issue for a long time, but can't find one solution.

Appreciate for any suggestions and solutions.

**Note:** I set up breakpoint at the entry of the class=`com.my.own.util.CustomUserDetailsMapper`, but it never been triggered, so I didn't enclose its codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found below configuration working well.

Below `<bean id="ldapAuthProvider">` **construct two arguments**,

**First arg**: it will verify the username and password which the end user fills in at the front end.

**Second arg**: once succeed to pass through the authenticator, it will invoke our own populator (`<bean class="com.my.own.util.MyCustomLdapAuthPopulator">`) to assign the appropriate roles or do something else you'd like.

```
<sec:authentication-manager>  
    <sec:authentication-provider 
        ref="ldapAuthProvider"
        >  
    </sec:authentication-provider>  
</sec:authentication-manager> 

<bean id="ldapAuthProvider"  
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider" >  
    <constructor-arg>  
        <bean id="authenticator"  
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">  
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />  
            <property name="userSearch">  
                <bean  
                    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">  
                    <constructor-arg value="dc=aaa,dc=bbb,dc=ccc" />  
                    <constructor-arg value="(sAMAccountName={0})" />  
                    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />  
                </bean>  
            </property>  
        </bean>  
    </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.my.own.util.MyCustomLdapAuthPopulator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <constructor-arg value="dc=aaa,dc=bbb,dc=ccc" />
                <property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
                <property name="ignorePartialResultException" value="true" />
                <property name="groupSearchFilter" value="(member={0})" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
</bean> 
<bean id="contextSource"  
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource" >  
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://xx.xx.xx.xx:389/" />
    <property name="userDn" value="domain\user1" />    
    <property name="password" value="user1_password" />
</bean>
```

Below is one simple implementation for our own populator.

```
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator;
public class MyCustomLdapAuthPopulator extends DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator {

    @Autowired
    public MyCustomLdapAuthPopulator(ContextSource contextSource, String groupSearchBase) {
        super(contextSource, groupSearchBase);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected Set<GrantedAuthority> getAdditionalRoles(DirContextOperations user, String username) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add((new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_XXX")));
        return authorities;
    }
}
```